# Movies & TV Tour Display Bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In the "Welcome to Stack Exchange" (Movies & TV) opening page for the TOUR, you cannot see the full questions, or answers. It is a weird error to already run into on my first moments on the site & made reading or understanding this introduction page(s) totally confusing especially since I'm just trying to figure out what this site is.

[image]

Does anyone know who I notify about this bug in the site?

Comment: Note that this appears to be the same on all sites (though I only checked here, SFF and SO).

Answer (score 4):

**This isn't a bug, this is a design choice**

In the tour, these are just example Question and Answers.  You are intended to be reading the text to the left, for example "Just questions...." or "... and answers".

I can somewhat see your point. Further down the stuff that slides in from the right *is* content you are expected to read.  This top section, they are just showing you what the content on the site looks like, to scale, and they can only fit in some of it.

> Does anyone know who I notify about this bug in the site?".

If in doubt, the best place to report bugs or ask questions about the site is here, the companion "meta" site.  Your original question was moved here as it is a better place for it.

This Movies and TV site is one of many here at StackExchange, and questions like this, relating to bugs or behavior of the site often relate to all of them rather than just one.  There is a [common meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for all of them, but in doubt, you can always start here.